# Keyboard in some programs & some keys in keyboard won't work until restart

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard, vlc-media-player

I am facing this weird keyboard issue lately.

Keyboard works only for first 10-15 mins in Firefox, vlc  etc but works in notepad always (except some keys wont work but works only after restart).

I tried famous combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> still won't fix it.

My OS is **Windows 7 professional**.

I am tired of OSK (on screen keyboard).

I also tried:  run this program. `"C:\Windows\system32\ctfmon.exe".`

But no use.

Comment: Is this a laptop? Or a desktop with USB keyboard?